# How do I Download efficiently with rsync?

Tags: rsync

A couple of questions related to one theme: downloading efficiently with Rsync.

Currently, I move files from an 'upload' folder onto a local server using rsync. Files to be moved are often dumped there, and I regularly run rsync so the files don't build up. I use '--remove-source-files' to remove files that have been transferred.

1) the '--delete' options that remove destination files have various options that allow you to choose *when* to remove the files. This would be handly for '--remove-source-files' since is seems that, by default, rsync only removes the files after *all* files have been transferred, rather than after each file; Othere than writing a script to make rsync transfer files one-by-one, is there a better way to do this?

2) on the same problem, if a large (single) file is transferred, it can only be deleted after the whole thing has been sucessfully moved. It strikes me that I might be able to use 'split' to split the file up into smaller chunks, to allow each to be deleted as the file downloads; is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.